What is the best way to reroute this 3" waste pipe
As part of a remodel, we removed a boxed-out soffit that was built into the ceiling that some cabinets were hung from. We want to open up the space more and make the ceiling flat.
When we took the soffit down, we found drain pipes from the toilets upstairs. We want to reroute this plumbing into the ceiling so that it does not hang down into the kitchen space.
I have had several plumbers tell me that this can't be done in a way that will be code-compliant and told me I need to box in these pipes again. This sounds like a terrible option at this point so I want to try this myself. I have a lot of experience with PVC irrigation but nothing this big.
My plan is to extend both the 3" waste pipes through one more additional joist, and then connect them together with a wye + 45° so we can route them into the wall where the pipe comes up from the basement. I am confident that we can maintain a slope of at least 1/8" per foot throughout which I believe is code in our area.
The joists are 14". The holes will be 2" from the bottom. I will have to cut one hole at an angle as the wye will partially extend into the hole.
Any reasons that this wouldn't work? What are some things I should watch out for?



So the professionals said it can't be done to code, but you believe you can?  Your dismissal of the obvious leak damage concerns me.

The horizontal pipes must have a slope.  I believe it is a minimum of 1/8 inch per foot.  You are also limited to how much you can cut from the joists, unless you want the ceiling on your head.  The floor/ceiling and the joist at the left seems like it might need checking for rot/mold.

Incidentally, when we opened up the ceiling, surprise! lots of water damage. So the bathroom upstairs is getting gutted and the rotten subfloor is getting replaced. The joists look like they are in good shape as far as water damage is concerned. Trying to figure out how to approach this issue with the drain routing since it might be easier with the subfloor removed.

Even if you could raise those pipes up, the holes in those joists are at the maximum size allowed.  You would need to beef up those joists for larger holes or replace them and make new holes higher up in the joist.

Not enlarging any existing holes. Just adding 2 new holes in the next joist.

I didn't think up this plan until after the plumbers told me no or I would have asked them when they were here. I am thinking the plumbers either didn't think to do it this way or I dont understand their concern. If this is a bad idea I just want to understand why...

Is there room for a waste pipe with the HVAC duct there already?

@crip659 according to R502.8.1, holes can be bored up to 1/3 of the depth (4-2/3" in this case), as long as they're at least 2" from top or bottom.  That leaves 10" of vertical area where a hole can be located.  Surely sufficient slope can be had here, even if the OP has to rebore in new locations.  These are also a possibilty: https://metwood.com/product/joist-repair-hole-reinforcer-2810hr/
